# Wrong doctype when attempting to use HTML5 in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, doctype

In my asp.net 3.5 project I have tried changing the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the master page, but what is actually rendered on the page is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "" "">`, which of course does not validate.

Any tips of what can be causing this?

Comment: Are you adding the DOCTYPE inside the 
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:Content> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio are you using? If you have 2010 SP1 or 2012, you can select HTML5 from the options:

[image]

If you are still stuck, show us where you have declared the doctype and tell us which version of VS you are using.